# ¿Cómo hago la extracción del año de una consulta?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de hacer la extracción del año en una consulta ya hecha.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
a = users.objects.filter(fecha_ingreso__month=mes).values('usuario_id','nombre', 'fecha_ingreso')
```

Y lo que trato de hacer es los valores que trae meterlos a otra variable el año del campo de `fecha_ingreso`.

¿Cómo le puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendí muy bien, pero ahí va. El método [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values) del `QuerySet` te retorna diccionarios con los campos que le has pasado, en tu caso sería con los campos: `usuario_id`, `nombre` y `fecha_ingreso`.

Lo que te retornaría tu query `a` sería algo como esto:

```
<QuerySet [{'usuario_id': 1, 'nombre': 'Roberto', 'fecha_ingreso': datetime.date(2017, 8, 9)}]>
```

Eso, asumiendo que tu campo `fecha_ingreso` sea del tipo `DateField`. Si quisieras extraer el año de cada registro dentro tu query, tendrías que hacer:

```
>>> a = users.objects.filter(fecha_ingreso__month=mes).values('usuario_id','nombre', 'fecha_ingreso')
>>> years = [registro['fecha_ingreso'].year for registro in a]
>>> years
[2017, 2017, 2016]
```

Simplemente estás extrayendo el año (usando la propiedad `year` del objeto `datetime.date`).

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes.

lo que trato de hacer con lo que trae 'a' es de tratar de sacar la antiguedad que tiene los usuarios, mas que nada trato de hacer una resta.

resta = fecha_actual - a.fecha_ingreso, pero esto me marca error y la verdad no se como plasmar esto en codigo.

por eso trate de sacar la fecha pero creo que esta mal todo mi proceso y no supe como plantearlo.